# Passing a hex value in app.config file

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, c#-4.0, app-config

I am working on a c# web service. I have a special requirement where I need a configurable hexadecimal value in my code. I need to copy this hexadecimal value in a byte variable. I am trying to pass it in app.config file through appSettings.

For e.g.

```
byte ASCII_VALUE = 0xA5;
```

I want to get this 0xA5 from the app.config file and copy it to ASCII_VALUE.

I am currently using the following code in app.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Ascii_value" value="0xA5"/>
</appSettings>
```

and in my c# code I am doing:

```
byte ASCII_VALUE = (byte)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ascii_value_for_pound"];
```

But as this is a string it wont convert it to byte value directly.

I also tried

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Ascii_value" value="&#xA5;"/>
</appSettings>
```

and the same code in c#. But I am still not able to figure out as what to do to get the hex value.

Any idea Guys??? Please help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

What need to do is

In app.config

```
<add key="Ascii_value" value="A5"/>
```

In c#

```
string strAsciiValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ascii_value"];
int intAsciiValue = Int32.Parse(strAsciiValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
byte ASCII_VALUE = (byte)intAsciiValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you may want to take a look at [SoapHexBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it parses Hex strings directly and gives you Byte values with its `Value` property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Byte.Parse`?

Here is the MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/4eszwye3.aspx

You can override the method to accept hex.

This is the MSDN example:
 `byte val = Byte.Parse(num, NumberStyles.HexNumber);`

Comment: I did try that method. But the string is in hex format. This parse method only accept the string in number format. like "123".

Comment: I found a solution to this. :D

Comment: @Govs Please, post your solution as answer here